# Parameterless lambda expressions in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, unit-type

I am looking for a way to define Parameterless lambda expressions in F#, much like the following C# example.

```
var task = () => {
                     int x = 3;
                     DoSomething(x);
                 }
```

I tried the following

```
let task = fun _ -> 
              let x = 3
              doSomething x
```

It compiles but it gives me `task : ('a -> unit)` what I am actually looking for is `task : (unit -> unit)`

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233201.aspx) does not talk about this. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's just

```
let task = fun () -> // whatever you need
```

you example would be:

```
let task = fun () ->
              let x = 3
              DoSomething(3)
```

assuming `DoSomething` is of type `int -> unit` - if it returns something else you need

```
let task = fun () ->
              let x = 3
              DoSomething(3) |> ignore
```

to get type `unit -> unit`

**Remark:**
Usually you don't write `let task = fun () -> ...` but just `let task() = ...`

**The thing you missed:**
if you write `fun _ -> ()` you are saying you want to take some parameter that you don't mind about - so F# will take the most general (being named `'a` here) - this would include `unit`!
`()` is the only value of type `unit` (more or less `void` from C# ... but a true type in F#)